# <S:A> is resolved to empty bodied <a>

Tags: struts2

Not much to say, my `<s:a href="xxx">blablabla</s:a>` is aways resolved to empty and invisible `<a href="xxx"></a>`

I also tried s:a attributes like label, title, name, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The proper notation is

```
<s:a value="http://www.stackoverflow.com">Go to link</s:a>
```

And also make sure you got this at the top of your jsp.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
```

Comment: This also does not work actually! And I experienced that again trying to use links to actions: <s:a namespace="aaa" action="bbb">go</s:a>.
Just nothing on the page.

Comment: I just tried and both yuors and mine work.

I assume you forgot this:
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>